# How to transfer the list of strings in DTO using Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm developing Spring + Thymeleaf application. I'm implementing search with multiple params. I have a form with the corresponding DTO. Here is the code of the DTO:

```
public class ClassSearchDto {
   private String searchParam;
   private Long programId;
   private List<String> teacherNames;
   //getters, setters and constructor are omitted
}
```

As you see, I have a list of strings in my DTO called `teacherNames`. Here is the way I'm displaying my form:

```
 <form th:action="@{/classes/search}" method="get" th:object="${classSearchDto}">

    <div class="form-group">
       <input type="hidden" class="form-control"
          th:value="${classSearchDto.programId}" th:field="*{programId}"/>

       <label for="searchParam">Search</label>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchParam" placeholder="keyword"
                                       th:value="${classSearchDto.searchParam}" th:field="*{searchParam}"/>
       <div>
          <th:block th:each="name, iter ${classSearchDto.teacherNames}">
              <input th:value="${name}" th:field="*{teacherNames[__${iter.index}__]}/>
          </th:block>
       </div>

   </div>
   <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Find</button>

   </form>
```

I want to implement my search with help of `@RequestParam` annotation on the back-end. This is my controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/search")
 public String findClassByName(@RequestParam("searchParam") final String searchParam,
                              @RequestParam("programId") final Long programId,
                              @RequestParam("teacherNames") final List<String> teacherNames,
                              final Model model) {
 ...
 }
```

The problem is that I can't get the list of teacher names in this way. I get this exception:

```
 org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException:Required List parameter 'teacherNames' is not present
```

Could you please help me to transfer the list of elements in DTO to my back-end with this approach? Maybe you know how to do it correctly in another way. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest you one thing, I don't know  whether it works or not. Try changing

```
public String findClassByName(@RequestParam("searchParam") final String searchParam,@RequestParam("programId") final Long programId,@RequestParam("teacherNames") final List<String> teacherNames,final Model model)
```

to

```
public String findClassByName(@ModelAttribute("classSearchDto")  ClassSearchDto classSearchDto,@RequestParam("searchParam") String searchParam,@RequestParam("programId") Long programId,@RequestParam("teacherNames")  List<String> teacherNames,Model model)
```